# How to remove a method from an object instance conditioned by __init__ parameters?

Tags: python, oop

I would like to write a class that removes access to or throws an error in case a particular method is accessed and this behavior should be conditioned by a variable set upon class instantiation.

So in code I would like something like this:

```
class NewClass:

    def __init__(self, has_non_available_method):
        self.has_non_available_method = has_non_available_method

    def some_method(self):
        if self.has_non_available_method:
            raise SomeError()
```

This is fine however, if I want to have a couple of methods like this then I have to copy-paste these 2 lines into every method. Which "doesn't seem very sophisticated" and I would like to find out if a "better"/DRY approach exists.

I considered using decorators but decorators execute upon class execution so they do not seem to be suitable for this task as the attribute `has_non_available_method` (in this example) will not be set at that point.

Comment: Try `delattr`,https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#delattr

Comment: You can use a decorator for this. The decorator function can check `self.has_non_available_method` when it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator is perfect for this.

```
def checkavail(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.has_non_available_method:
            raise SomeError()
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class NewClass:

    def __init__(self, has_non_available_method):
        self.has_non_available_method = has_non_available_method

    @checkavail
    def some_method(self):
        # do stuff
```

Comment: I just tried running this code however I get a ```Type Error: 'NoneType' object is not callable``` if I try to instantiate ```NewClass``` and run ```instance.some_method()```. I added a print statement to ```some_method``` and substituted ```raise``` for another print statement. Could you tell me whats wrong?

Comment: I wasn't calling the method correctly from the decorator.

Comment: I think you need call `wrapper` in the decorator?

Comment: Forgot to return the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

### use decorator

- I add `decorate_all_functions`, so you don't need copy-paste the decorate itself to every class method.

#### code:

```
def decorate_all_functions(function_decorator):
    def decorator(self):
        for name, obj in vars(self).items():
            if callable(obj):
                try:
                    obj = obj.__func__
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  
                setattr(self, name, function_decorator(obj))
        return self
    return decorator

from functools import wraps
def check_permission(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if func.__name__ in self.has_non_available_method:
            raise Exception("Some Error")
        func(self,*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorate_all_functions(check_permission)
class NewClass:
    has_non_available_method = []
    def __init__(self, has_non_available_method):
        self.has_non_available_method = has_non_available_method

    def some_method(self):
        print("do something")

    def another_method(self):
        print("do another thing")

x = NewClass(["another_method"])
x.some_method()
try:
    x.another_method()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

#### result:

```
do something
Some Error
```

### use del

- You can try `delattr` or `del` to remove class method dynamically.

#### code:

```
class NewClass:

    def some_method(self):
        print("do something")

    def another_method(self):
        print("do another thing")

x = NewClass()
x.some_method()
x.another_method()
delattr(type(x),"some_method")
# del NewClass.some_method
# both work
try:
    x.some_method()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
x.another_method()
```

#### result:

```
do something
do another thing
'NewClass' object has no attribute 'some_method'
do another thing
```

- But it will remove the class method, not the instance.

```
y = NewClass()
y.some_method()#raise AttributeError
```

Comment: That will remove the method from the entire class, not just a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorator to make this behavior more dynamic.

```
def check_permission(method):
    def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, 'has_{}_permission'.format(method.__name__), False):
            method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise Exception('{} needs permission'.format(method.__name__))
    return call


class PermissionRequiredMethodClass(object):

    def __init__(self, has_secret_method_permission: bool = False):
        self.has_secret_method_permission = has_secret_method_permission
        super().__init__()

    def open_method(self):
        print('in open method')

    @check_permission
    def secret_method(self):
        # secret stuff
        print('in secret')
```